# How to Read MessagePack Response on Charles or Mitmproxy?

Tags: charles-proxy, msgpack, mitmproxy

Is there a way to convert MessagePack response on Charles/MITM to JSON?

I have a response from https://[...]/application/x-msgpack

Raw mode reads it:

> xdd\xb8\xbd\xc9? \x03\xa2Xe\xccO\xc2O\xd6"\x06\x91\xcfB\x9c\xed\x0fl

Hex mode reads it:

> 0000000010 06 91 cf 42 9c ed 0f 6c 2e 14 ae f1 da 2d 34 e9   ...B...l.....-4.

Hex mode contains contains nonsense at the end of every line.

Other modes could not parse and fall back to Raw mode.

If I fail to give you any other info, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you can decode it in Python (e.g. using Kaitai Struct), you can implement a mitmproxy contentview to display it in a human-readable way:

- https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/simple/custom_contentview.py
- https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/tree/master/mitmproxy/contentviews

(*if* you go the kaitai struct route - we'd also be more than happy for a PR!)

Comment: Awesome. Seems beyond my skill, but I will try using Kaitai Struct and see how far I can go. Thanks!